# css file in css folder not overrided in wordpress child theme

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a main.css file in a css folder in a wordpress theme, it's called in functions.php the way below

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'td-main',            THEME_WEB_ROOT . '/css/main.css' );
```

In my child theme I recreate a css folder at the same location than the parent, but it's not overwritten, here is my child theme functions.php

```
function theme_enqueue_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style('parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css');
    wp_enqueue_style('child-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css', array($parent_style));
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_enqueue_styles');
```

I thaught it was enough to recreate the file in the child theme, but can't figure why it's not working.
Do I do something wrong ?

Comment: `array('parent-style')` at the end